# Apache not passing through 404 error from API behind reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2.2

When I make a call using Postman to my API - which is behind a reverse proxy using Apache 2.2 - that returns a 404, I get the standard *404 Not Found* html returned instead of the error from the API.

How can I configure Apache to return the error from the API instead of serving it's own HTML?

The route lives inside a `<Location>` block:

```
<Location /service/api>
    ProxyPass http://docker1:6001
    ProxyPassReverse http://docker1:6001
</Location>
```

An example 404 call would be http://example.com/service/api/things/1234.

Comment: You might try the [`ProxyErrorOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyerroroverride) directive, which should pass through the error as-is when set to `off` (the default, in most cases).

Comment: @AfroThundr That's exactly what I ended up doing. Turning it off allowed the settings I had inside the `docker1` box to work properly. If you want to answer it properly I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>From [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313408/#comment98272311_55313408) earlier:</sup>

You might try the [`ProxyErrorOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyerroroverride) directive, which should pass through the error as-is when set to `off` (the default, in most cases).